# How to force application target to use one language in IOS?

Tags: ios, localization

I am trying to release 2 application with the same code. Therefore I created 2 targets, one for base language, one for international application. International app will have 5 localisation. Base app will only have base language localisation.

My problem is, even I build base application with base language, application translates the words into the phones current language.

What I need is, even the current language is not base language, app shouldn't translate the words into current language.

I hope it is clear.

Comment: Is the answer "don't include the foreign localisable.strings files in your other target" helpful? Or is that what you already think you're doing? Also be sure to clean and rebuild from Xcode to test if you change whether a file is in a project, as it only does a partial update otherwise and usually leaves in files that are now excluded.

Answer (score 1):

The Localization.strings file is per project not per target. 
You could put all the code into a static library and create two projects each of which link to the library. 
The two projects would be identical expect one has a single translation of Localization.strings and the other has 5 translations.